"Run Debugging" in Visual Studio Code doesn't work
I used to run Python code in Visual Studio Code using F5 or the "Run Debugging" function. Now however, when I press F5 nothing happens. I realized that I need to select a configuration for running the code, but the only option available is "JavaScript Debug Terminal" which doesn't do anything when I try to run it.
launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node-terminal",
            "name": "JavaScript Debug Terminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

This problem has affected both my PC and laptop so it might be related to some extensions for Visual Studio Code. This problem is similar. I modified the JSON configuration file. I disabled extensions keeping only necessary ones, as well as completely reinstalling Visual Studio Code. None of these helped.

Have you done a sanity check that the F5 key is working? Like opening a browser and pressing F5 to refresh the page. The only thing I can think of is you accidentally hit FN lock-- I would expect F5 to do something in VS Code, like open Command Palette or bring up an error message...

Yes, the F5 button work fine, the problen not here

You could open your Run And Debug tab then add the configuration like the following figure:

Then choose the Python Debugger.

You could also add the codes to your launch.json manually.
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
        "type": "debugpy",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
]

If you cannot see this option, you have to install Python Debugger extension.

This is because the debugger was once included in the python extension and is now released as a separate extension.
